# Right way to sync a variable with UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, userdefaults

I would like to keep a variable sync with UserDefaults directly when I set a value. I've done it like this:

```
var userId: String {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: kUserIdKey) ?? ""
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: kUserIdKey)
    }
}
```

It is working fine but is it the right way to do it?

If so, what about Array?

```
var tagsList: [Int] {
    get {
        return (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: kTagsList) as? [Int]) ?? [Int]()
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: kTagsList)
    }
}
```

If I add an element `tagsList.append(0)`, is the new value stored in UserDefaults?

**Update**.

Here is what I have in the playground:
[image]

Comment: did you try to debug it and check how looks `newValue`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: Arrays and Strings are `struct`s in Swift, which semantically make a whole new copy when mutated.

The `newValue` in the setter therefore is the resulting array of whatever mutation you applied to the array, whether it being an `append` or other mutating functions.

You can easily verify this behavior in a playground like this:

```
var array: [Int] {
    get { return [1, 2, 3] }
    set { print(newValue) }
}

array.append(4)
// Prints [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

> If I add an element tagsList.append(0), is the new value stored in UserDefaults?

**YES.**

At a glance, you have a setter and, as a setter, it only observes the value whenever you make a new assignment, like:

`tagsList = [1,2,3]` // new value.

If `Array<Int>` (`[Int]`) was class we could say that, even though you do modify the existing array by calling `append`, this is not an assignment, per se. However, `[Int]` is not a `class`, it's a `struct` which means that any function that modifies (*mutates*, to be correct) existing `struct`, basically leads to a new assignment.  This is the reason why you would see setter to trigger.